# How to get users' step count when app is not opened in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need all users' step count of my app.

And even when users don't open an app, this keeps counting user's pedometer and that data should be counted and applied in app when app is opened.

For this,
`expo-pedometer` is possible ? and `Google Fit` also provide this ?

I don't want to ruin my app when I install all of them.

But each library's scope is not explained in detail.

For this purpose, How can I approach in React Native?

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll need to ask permissions to the user to do that. But first of all, what did you try before asking?

Comment: of course I will ask permissions to users, what you mean ' what did you try before asking? '. my purpose is to get all users' step count and sort them in order and show this data to users in my app. but as I mention above, this step count needs to be counted even when app is not opened. And i want to know which library is good for this purpose in RN.

Comment: What a meant is that you need to provide the code you have tried so that we can help you to improve it.

Comment: I didn't install or write code yet, because I don't know which library is proper for my purpose  my question is which library will be good for this. then I can select that and install, write code

Comment: hey - did you ever manage to do this? i'm struggling with the same thing

Comment: @EvyatarShafran aww..it was 9 months ago,, eventually I changed language from RN to kotlin to achieve background work smoothly, of course, still it is a bit hard to make 24/7 work but it's better than with react native.